# Fedex not working on Magento 1.9.1.0 + Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, magento, soap, ubuntu-14.04, magento-1.9.1

Migrating to a new Ubuntu 14 server with php 5.5 & Magento 1.9.1.0 from 1.7.0.2

Fedex does not seem to pull rates. All credentials are the same from 1.7.0.2

I've displayed the log file below from the debug.

Installed latest version of SOAP.

```html
2015-01-23T06:02:37+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => TX9aAheEUqPV5Bej
                            [Password] => lFi0xCAVSEkzxP2L52RSfu7uP4
                        )

                )

            [ClientDetail] => Array
                (
                    [AccountNumber] => 495055147
                    [MeterNumber] => 121492979
                )

            [Version] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

            [RequestedShipment] => Array
                (
                    [DropoffType] => BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2015-01-23T06:02:37+00:00
                    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                    [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Amount] => 76.28
                            [Currency] => USD
                        )

                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 92614
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 92804
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                    [Residential] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => 495033147
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomsValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 76.28
                                    [Currency] => USD
                                )

                        )

                    [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                    [PackageCount] => 1
                    [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                    [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 2.6
                                            [Units] => 
                                        )

                                    [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                    [InsuredValue] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Amount] => 76.28
                                            [Currency] => USD
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => Fault
            [code] => 0
        )

    [__pid] => 2875
)

2015-01-23T06:02:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => Array
        (
            [WebAuthenticationDetail] => Array
                (
                    [UserCredential] => Array
                        (
                            [Key] => TX9aAheEUqPV3Bej
                            [Password] => lFi0xCn7JkzxP2L52RSfu7uP4
                        )

                )

            [ClientDetail] => Array
                (
                    [AccountNumber] => 495033147
                    [MeterNumber] => 107492979
                )

            [Version] => Array
                (
                    [ServiceId] => crs
                    [Major] => 10
                    [Intermediate] => 0
                    [Minor] => 0
                )

            [RequestedShipment] => Array
                (
                    [DropoffType] => BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER
                    [ShipTimestamp] => 2015-01-23T06:02:39+00:00
                    [PackagingType] => YOUR_PACKAGING
                    [TotalInsuredValue] => Array
                        (
                            [Amount] => 76.28
                            [Currency] => USD
                        )

                    [Shipper] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 92614
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [Recipient] => Array
                        (
                            [Address] => Array
                                (
                                    [PostalCode] => 92804
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                    [Residential] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [ShippingChargesPayment] => Array
                        (
                            [PaymentType] => SENDER
                            [Payor] => Array
                                (
                                    [AccountNumber] => 495033147
                                    [CountryCode] => US
                                )

                        )

                    [CustomsClearanceDetail] => Array
                        (
                            [CustomsValue] => Array
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 76.28
                                    [Currency] => USD
                                )

                        )

                    [RateRequestTypes] => LIST
                    [PackageCount] => 1
                    [PackageDetail] => INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES
                    [RequestedPackageLineItems] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Weight] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Value] => 2.6
                                            [Units] => 
                                        )

                                    [GroupPackageCount] => 1
                                    [InsuredValue] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Amount] => 76.28
                                            [Currency] => USD
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => Fault
            [code] => 0
        )

    [__pid] => 2866
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right API urls:
Go to the file `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`

And check the line 135. If it looks like this:

```
$client->__setLocation($this->getConfigFlag('sandbox_mode')
    ? 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate'
    : 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/rate'
);
```

Temporarily change it to:

```
$client->__setLocation($this->getConfigFlag('sandbox_mode')
    ? 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services'
    : 'https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services'
);
```

If it works, you should extend the model with your own module, to properly override urls, or alternatively copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`

Comment: also, can you put the output of var/logs/exceptions.log? (if exists)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with Fedex.php from 1.7.0.2